# Extending Bell Numbers to Fractional Values

Tags: summation, bell-numbers

An identity of the Bell numbers is given by
$$B_n=\frac{1}{e}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{x!}$$
and I was wondering if it would be valid to define fractional Bell numbers in the same way, to preserve this identity. So, to calculate what I would take as $B_{1/2}$, I would have to calculate 
$$\frac{1}{e}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt x}{x!}$$
However, I have no idea how to calculate this sum, and I am afraid that it may not have a closed form.

Can somebody show me how to evaluate this, or a better way to define fractional Bell numbers?

**NOTE:** I am thinking that perhaps I can express
$$\frac{\sqrt x}{x!}$$
in the form
$$\int_a^b f(x,n)\,dn$$
for some $a$, $b$, $f$, so that I can convert my sum into an integral. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: if there is an integral representation probably it can be extended by analytic continuation. Try to see for what values of $w$ [this integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Integral_representation) make sense $$B_w = \frac{\Gamma(w+1)}{2 \pi i e} \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{e^z}}{z^{w+1}} \, dz. $$

Comment: searching for "generalized Bell numbers" I found some proposals (not sure if equivalent or different). In particular [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.1700.pdf) seems interesting by it geometrical interpretation. I will add also [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL14/Mezo/mezo9.pdf) that seems interesting because it is an understandable extension of the Bell numbers.

Comment: the extension of Bell Numbers to complex arguments  through the integral cited by Masacroso is well discussed in [this article](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00073316/file/RR-3373.pdf)

Comment: I studied generalized Bell-numbers as an exercise for myself. Maybe you like http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/04_5_SummingBellStirling.pdf